# hide/leave visible each element if the condition is true/false

Tags: jquery

My code hides all buttons. I do not know how to correctly write this correctly to hide or leave a visible button at each next condition `if (text <= 16)`

```
$(".card").each(function(i, e) {
  var text = $(e).text().length;
  if (text <= 16) {
    console.log(text);
    $(".btn").each(function(i, e) {
      $(this).hide()
    });
  }
});


 UPD HTML

    <div class="container">
  {% for image, title, text in imageTitles %}
  <hr>
  <h3>
        <p class="text-center ">{{ title }}</p>
  </h3>
  <img class="col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ image }}>
  <div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse">
      <div class="card card-body">
        {{text}}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <script>
    $(".card").each(function(i,e){
    var text = $(e).text().length;
      if (text <=16) {
        console.log(text);
        $(".btn").each(function(i,e){
          $(this).hide()
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Do you only want to hide the buttons where their text is < 16? Please clarify. Also seeing your HTML would help here

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: Is your buttons inside card that must be hidden? Or you need to hide every button on page.

Comment: i need hide each button if each element less 16.
for example i have 3 elems and 3 buttons.  if first elem <= 16 than first button should be hide, if second elem<=16, second button should be hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all `.btn` when at least one of `.card` is less then 16 length:

```
$(".card").each(function(){
    $(".btn").toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
});
```

To hide all `.btn` *inside* `.card`:

```
$(".card").each(function(){
    $(".btn", this).toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
});
```

---

With clarified issue: Select `.card`, reach for common parent of card and button, select button, hide it.

```
$(".card").each(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest('.collapse-group')
        .find('.btn')
        .toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
});
```

Comment: i need hide each button if each element less 16. for example i have 3 elems and 3 buttons. if first elem <= 16 than first button should be hide, if second elem<=16, second button should be hide

Comment: works but vice versa, where the field <= 16 button is visible

Comment: @ZhaZha Sorry, my bad. Use `>` instead

Answer (score 0):

I can see a sequence issue in your code.  Please try this

```
$(".card").each(function(i,e){
    var text = $(e).text().length;

        console.log(text);
        $(".btn").each(function(i,e){

                       if (text <=16) {
                                        $(this).hide();
                                      }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM relationship to target the related elements. You can use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get desired cards having text-length then use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up common ancestor. Afterwards using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the button

```
//Start with displaying all buttons
$(".btn").show();

//Filter cards having text < 16
var cards = $(".card").filter(function (i, e) {
    return $(this).text().trim().length <= 16;
});

//Target related buttons and hide them
cards.closest('.collapse-group').find(".btn").hide();
```

```js
//Start with displaying all buttons
$(".btn").show();

//Filter cards having text < 16
var cards = $(".card").filter(function(i, e) {
  return $(this).text().trim().length <= 16;
});

//Target related buttons and hide them
cards.closest('.collapse-group').find(".btn").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Lore
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need hide each button if each element less 16. for example i have 3 elems and 3 buttons. if first elem <= 16 than first button should be hide, if second elem<=16, second button should be hide